# Fields_for method in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the difference between this:

## controller

@user = User.new
@order = Order.new

## view:

```
<%= form_for :user do |user| %>
    ...
    ...
    <%= fields_for :order do |order| %>
    ...
    ...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I can extract the values in the params-object like this params[:user] and params[:order]

But I could also have written:

```
<%= form_for :user do |user| %>
    ...
    ...
    <%= user.fields_for :order do |order| %>
    ...
    ...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and I could have extracted the values in the params-object like this params[:user][:order].

**Is the equal, distinguished by the way I extract values from?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you would use the nested version of `fields_for` if you were using this line in your `User` model:

```
has_many :orders
accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders
```

By defining this, you will be able to create a new user and new order record**s** at the same time by using this in the `create` action of your `UsersController`:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

Because you're using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` now, the order attributes will be passed through as `params[:user][:orders_attributes]`.